# Localhost Youtube embed issue

Tags: iframe, youtube, localhost, embed

Tried to embed youtube iframe to my local running site,

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but it shows:

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

If to test embed youtube iframe in local, any best practice or method to overcome this ?

Comment: There is similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714879/error-parsing-header-x-xss-protection-google-chrome
And it seems, there is still no solution on that because of browser..