# Youtube video not playing : Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am getting the javascript console error as:  Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

I checked the previous questions and answers, and according to one suggestion I updated my chrome version to 66. But still, the youtube video is not playing properly, just throwing black screen. Is there anything I can do to fix it from my end as a developer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714879/error-parsing-header-x-xss-protection-google-chrome

Comment: where is the link of that video?

Comment: It is an embedded video link